# API de camera2?

Tags: javascript, api

Alguém sabe onde posso encontrar api de camera2 em javascript??

API para utilizar em apps quem precisa ser capturada uma imagem e enviada 
como o snapchat entre outros

Comment: Vai usar um webView?

Comment: tentarei pq tenho mt curiosidade